# Create a completely transparent JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt, transparency

I have the following class

```
public class FileCopyManager extends JFrame{

   public static final Color TRANSPARENT_COLOR = new Color(0,0,0,0);
   public FileCopyManager(){
     this.setBackgroundColor(TRANSPARENT_COLOR);
   }
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(()->{
             try {
                UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
            }
            catch (Throwable e) {
            }
            finally{
                new FileCopyManager();
            }
         });
    }
}
```

However when I try to run this program I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated
    at java.awt.Frame.setBackground(Unknown Source)
```

Any Ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well just use `this.setUndecorated(true)`